# Why \usebox (is it vestigial)?

Tags: boxes

Despite my inflammatory title, I understand that `\usebox` is employed to display a predefined box.  But this question concerns when [the use of the box register, rather than the box content] becomes absolutely essential to a LaTeX operation (for example, as arguments to `\wd`, `\ht`, and `\dp`). [EDITS above and below in brackets, to reflect proper terminology]

---

Clarifying, based on Werner's comments, given the syntax

```
\newsavebox{\xyz}
\sbox{\xyz}{...}
\def\xyzbox{\usebox{\xyz}}
```

are there useful things I can perform only upon [the register] `\xyz` that I cannot perform on [the box content] `\xyzbox`?

(If not, then maybe `\usebox` is vestigial).

---

For example, consider the LaTeX syntax

```
\newsavebox{\xyz}
\sbox{\xyz}{...}
\usebox{\xyz}
```

Why couldn't LaTeX have been constructed so that the last line could have been issued as `\xyz`, without the `\usebox` (saving me a few characters of typing)?  I am so frustrated [an exaggeration] with the `\usebox` syntax, that I work around it in both the `verbatimbox` package and the `\stackengine` package. In the former, I allow this syntax:

```
\begin{myverbbox}[]{\boxname}
...
\end{myverbbox}
\boxname% <--NOTE: THIS IS NOT \usebox{\boxname}
```

Internally, `\boxname` actually points to `\usebox{boxnamecontent}`

Likewise, in `stackengine`, I allow:

```
\savestack{\mystack}{VARIOUS STACKING COMMANDS}
\mystack% <---NOTE: THIS IS NOT \usebox{\mystack}
```

Internally, `\mystack` actually points to `\usebox{\mystackcontent}`

So the crux of my question is this?  When is the [use of a box register] essential to a LaTeX operation??

I realize things like `\wd`, `\ht`, and `\dp` act on the un-rendered box name itself (without the `\usebox`); however, even these are replaceable by `calc`'s `\widthof`, `\heightof`, and `\depthof`, which act upon the (rendered) `\usebox` version of the box.

So what other TeX/LaTeX operations act upon [the box register, rather than the content]?  In essence (rhetorically), why do we still need `\usebox` syntax if everything that acts upon a box acts upon the rendered `\usebox` form of the box?

[So far, the answers have revealed that I need the box register to set the box, and to use the box.  And I can, but don't need to, use the register to measure the box.  And in nebulous places where I "need a number, not... a box".

Any other usages of the box register?]

Comment: You know that `\def\usebox#1{\leavevmode\copy #1\relax}`...

Comment: @Werner I don't know that, and what does it mean? (i.e., what are the implications?)

Comment: ...perhaps you might want to just declare `\newsavebox{\xyz}` and also `\def\xyzbox{\usebox\xyz}`.

Comment: @Werner Yes, that is exactly what I do (for the user) in the two packages I mention.  The question is WHY make me spend the extra typing?  Or, alternately, are there useful tasks (using the syntax of your comment) that I can only perform on `\xyz` and not on `\xyzbox`?

Comment: Why? I don't know. That's just the way it is might also be an answer.

Comment: @Werner Implicit in my question is whether I am robbing the user of `\verbatimbox` and `stackengine` any capability when I bypass the `\usebox` syntax with the `myverbbox` environment and `\savestack` macro??

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes with this definition you can do `\box\xyz` and `\ifvoid\xyz empty\else not empty\fi`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

TeX provides us with macros and registers. Macros are (simply) replaced by their definition, and so are used 'raw'. LaTeX wraps this concept up in `\newcommand`, with the result that

```
\newcommand{\foo}{....}
```

can then be used as simply `\foo`. On the other hand, registers have to be correctly accesses, at least in places where TeX does not 'expect' them. Again, LaTeX provides interfaces, for example

```
\newcounter{foo}
\value{foo}
```

which does the same as the TeX construct

```
\newcount\c@foo
\the\c@foo
```

Notably, using the register here needs an accessor function.

Boxes are registers, which while they don't quite work in the same way as other ones do broadly follow the same rules. In particular, they are not macros, so

```
\newsavebox{\foo}
\sbox{\foo}{...}
\foo
```

would be inconsistent: `\foo` looks like a command (macro), but cannot be set using `\newcommand`, *etc.* There are also places where TeX 'expects' a reference to a box, not the typeset content of a box. As you almost point out, those are not LaTeX constructs (`\wd` is not a LaTeX command but a TeX primitive not moved 'out of the way' by LaTeX2e). However, in general the LaTeX2e kernel does leave us able to use plain TeX constructs along with LaTeX ones as a lot of the programming for LaTeX2e is done that way. Thus breaking

```
\newsavebox{\foo}% or \newbox\foo in TeX syntax
\wd\foo
```

would be problematic. (So would having `\newsavebox` and `\newbox` work fundamentally differently.)

Worth noting in this context is that

```
\ifdim\wd\somebox=...
```

is an expandable construct, while `\widthof` and similar are not expandable (they typeset the material in a temporary box for measurement). As such, while the `\ifdim\wd` syntax is TeX, not LaTeX, there are advantages to using it (*e.g.* works inside a `\dimexpr`). Thus there are things that are much easier/clearer to do using the register number rather than the content of the box.

Comment: Consistency. It is indeed essential. But funny you mention counters as the metaphor, because LaTeX provides a macro form to access these registers, as in `\thecounter` being the macro form of `\arabic{counter}` (or is it `\value`, I can't recall). So why not `\xyzbox` or some similar syntax to be the same as `\usebox{xyz}`? But the real underlying question I had was in learning what circumstances (other than `\usebox`) require a LaTeX user to access the box register, rather than the box content?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes `\the<counter>` is a command (macro) and so can be altered using `\renewcommand`. This is however available _in addition_ to the method of accessing counters using `\setcounter`/`\value`, _etc._, and is there as `\the<counter>` might produce more than just a number. As well as `\usebox`, you need the box name for setting the box (`\sbox`, `\setbox`, _etc._).

Comment: So, if I may follow up, I need to use the box register to set the box (check).  And I used to need the register to measure the box, but the `\widthof` type commands of `calc` allow me to get around that.  And I need the register to display the box via `\usebox`.  Are there any other circumstances that come to mind, requiring use of the box register?

Answer (score 16):

All LaTeX box commands effectively start with `\leavevmode` this is an important aspect of LaTeX acting in a consistent and understandable way.

after `\savebox\xyz{abc}`  then `\usebox\xyz` acts like `\mbox{xyz}` whereas `\copy\xyz` acts like `\hbox{xyz}` and does not start a paragraph.

`\xyz` on its own is just a number referring to the box register so it can be used where you need a number, not where you need a box.

Comment: Don't get me wrong.  I love boxes.  You probably know I use them all of the time.  I understand the need for internal consistency, registers, etc.  Much of that is transparant to the casual user.  So, while my title may be a bit facetious, I really was interested to know when (i.e., what LaTeX macros) need to refer to the box register itself.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I'm not sure I understand your question here or in comments on the main question. You need to refer to the register whenever you need to refer to it. If you don't need to refer to it then you don't need to save the content in a box register at all. It is like asking when you need to use a variable in other programming languages. Basically if you need to refer to something more than once then it might be worth saving it in a register.

Comment: It really goes back to those shortcuts I mentioned in `verbatimbox` and `stackengine` where I give the user a macro that (from his perspective) bypasses the register (i.e., the package keeps track of the register, in an effort to save the user a few keystrokes).  I got to wondering if I'm shortchanging the user who may feel at a loss with my packages if he has to access the box registers (and hasn't delved deep in the package documentation to see how).  So, I was trying to ascertain all the types of operations using box registers, to anticipate if a user might ever need those with my packages.